# Get nice name of category from slug (remove dashes of category)

Tags: php, categories, urls, slug

I have a function in a theme:

```
$category = isset($_GET['category']) ? wp_unslash($_GET['category']) : '';
```

The problem is that it outputs my categories like this:

"test-category"

I want, however, to show: **"Test Category"**, just like it's saved in the backend, without the dashes and the smaller letters.

Is there a way I can get rid of this slug and use the nicename instead? I tried a lot of things (like the `get_term_by()` function), but nothing works for me. I guess it's because of the fact that I am using the $category variable.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Could you show how you used the `get_term_by()`? because, assuming that the taxonomy is category, `get_term_by('slug', $category, 'category')` should return the category object, if exists.

Comment: can you share what you tried with `get_term_by`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a sucker for regular expressions:

```
<?php
$category = 'test-category';
$category = preg_replace('/-/', ' ', $category);
$category = ucwords($category); 
echo $category;
```

Comment: I think OP means that he want the name of the taxonomy, if he indeed only wants to strip dashes and lower case then this is great, but if he want the name of the taxonomy it will not always return the correct result, you can have slug different from name.

Answer (score 0):

First, get the term object via `get_term_by`:

```php
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', 'test-category', 'category' );
```

Then grab the display name from the [term object](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/):

```php
echo esc_html( $term->name );
```

Note that if it fails to find the term, `get_term_by` will return `false` instead, so always check for this.